# Stretch, resize, or thumbnail an image using Perl

Tags: perl, thumbnails

How can I stretch or resize an image (of any format) using a Perl script?

Comment: You might want to Google questions like that.

Comment: You might want to Google any question on stackoverflow. But you may also ask it here.

Comment: Google does not help much here, because there are too many solutions available and it is hard to find a really good one. I am so glad this questions was asked. Because until now I always used Image::Resize with GD and it was always a mess (for me). Image::Imlib2 fits my needs much better!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend Image::Imlib2... if you can install imlib2 on your machine

See documentation: [Image::Imlib2](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Image-Imlib2/lib/Image/Imlib2.pm)

```
use Image::Imlib2;

# load image from file
my $image = Image::Imlib2->load("in.png");

# get some info if you want
my $width  = $image->width;
my $height = $image->height;

# scale the image down to $x and $y
# you can set $x or $y to zero and it will maintain aspect ratio
my $image2 = $image->create_scaled_image($x,$y);

# save thumbnail to file
$image2->save("out.png");
```

You might also be interested in [Image::Imlib2::Thumbnail](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Image-Imlib2-Thumbnail/lib/Image/Imlib2/Thumbnail.pm), if you can not install imlib2 have a look at [Image::Magick](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PerlMagick/Magick.pm)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Image::Resize](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/Image-Resize/Image/Resize.html).

Comment: yeah .. cool and simple. :) I didn't want to give that one because some people might not have/want to install the library hehe

Comment: If you use GD anyway it is a nice interface. If you need to additionally install GD just to make some thumbnails I would not recommend it. I had several problems installing GD on new versions... and this broke my code.